# Get coordinates of two mouses separately in C++

Tags: c++, mouse

I'm having two mouses on my PC, and now I want to get their positions at the same time. Can I do this through programming?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can but it's very dependant on operating system, making your question to broad to answer.

Comment: The system doesn't typically assign a coordinate for a _mouse_. Normally, there's a _cursor_ (pointer) that has a coordinate, and with multiple mice attached, each can change the coordinate but there's only one coordinate to retrieve.

Comment: probably, at least in Linux/X environment. Depending on interface OS uses to control pointing device, not really on programming language. But, as said, question is too broad to answer. Technically it is only number of constituents/components you need to describe event. Imagine mouse as 3-buttons device: X1, Y1 and one button W1. Moving cursor is like pressing one or more buttons paralelly, so adding another mouse is adding a set of another three "buttons", X2, Y2 and W2. Depending on how many buttons single mouse has (scroll etc.), it creates more combinations. Google for Xorg two mouse.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you cant, because you can only get the Position of the Cursor which is controlled by every mice.

Comment: Can I use Linux to realize this?

Comment: AFAIR default behaviour you might expect on Xorg/Linux is when you connect other mouse ( or other pointing device ), only one will be detected by X as primary, it may be possible to control one pointer with two devices interchangeably. Not sure if two separate pointers support is implemented, things change too fast these days :) but it's certainly possible it is implemented, and even if it isn't, it's possible to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, it's definitely possible to control one cursor with two devices. For instance I have a touchscreen and a mouse, the most recent one to be used moves the cursor.
     [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/q/45268/142515) talks about a [package which allows 2 cursors](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/MPX) on Ubuntu.

Comment: Now I want to control two cursors with two devices and get positions of two cursors

Comment: That's what the "X/MPX" software (in the link) will allow.